# Initialization code: real life examples?

Tags: apex

I don't know if anyone uses initialization code in production, I mean this one:

`{
   // instance initialization code here
}`

I don't see any benefits for using it at all. Yes, it can run before a constructor, but who cares. You can always put it inside a constructor and stop thinking what runs first. Are there any benefits of using this technique?

Comment: can't say i've ever used it in 5+ yrs on the platform

Answer (score 2):

The related pattern of `static {}` is useful - in that case there is no constructor.

Here is an example - code that uses that mechanism to build the reverse form of a map of `SObjectField` objects:

```
private static final Map<SObjectField, SObjectField> A_TO_CR = new Map<SObjectField, SObjectField>{
        Allocation__c.AllocatedNetAmount__c => ClaimRelationship__c.AllocatedNetAmount__c,
        Allocation__c.AllocatedNetPercentage__c => ClaimRelationship__c.AllocatedNetPercentage__c,
        Allocation__c.NetExceptAllocated__c => ClaimRelationship__c.NetExceptAllocated__c
        };

private static final Map<SObjectField, SObjectField> CR_TO_A = new Map<SObjectField, SObjectField>();
static {
    for (SObjectField key : A_TO_CR.keySet()) {
        CR_TO_A.put(A_TO_CR.get(key), key);
    }
}
```

But I've never used the non-static form.

Comment: I agreed with that. But what's only for static, not instance initialization.

Comment: @minige As I said I've never used the non-static form so personally do not see any benefits to using that form. And as you say using both forms may require you to know the order of execution which is again personally I don't.